# remove only matching word from file in java

Tags: java, regex, string, io

Hi i have a file contain some word , my requirement is to remove the matching word.If word is remove from between the line rest of the word below  has to shifted up to avoid  white space.

```
File.txt

medical_data01
medical_data02
medical_data
Census_data_10000_k.gen
Census_data_10000_k.gen_01
Census_data_10000_k.gen_02
```

If i remove `medical_data`
Output should come like this

```
medical_data01
medical_data02
Census_data_10000_k.gen
Census_data_10000_k.gen_01
Census_data_10000_k.gen_02
```

But my code output is coming like this

```
01
  02

    Census_data_10000_k.gen
    Census_data_10000_k.gen_01
    Census_data_10000_k.gen_02

File file = new File(
                RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString("tested"));
        File temp = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt",
                file.getParentFile());
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String delete = "medical_data";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),
                        charset));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp),
                        charset));
        String currentLine;
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            currentLine = currentLine.replace(delete,"");
            if (currentLine.equals("")) {

            } else
                writer.println(currentLine);
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        file.delete();
        temp.renameTo(file);
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: Your question is not very clear - do you want to remove the entire line that matches a pattern (e.g. `medical_data*`) ? If so, you may like to skip the matched pattern, instead of replacing it. Take a look at Scanner API to match using regexp as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove only 'medical_data' you need to change this code:

```
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            currentLine = currentLine.replace(delete,"");
            if (currentLine.equals("")) {
            } else
                writer.println(currentLine);
        }
```

to this code:

```
while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!currentLine.equals(delete)) {              
                writer.println(currentLine);
            }
        }
```

Then the output file looks like this:

```
medical_data01
medical_data02
Census_data_10000_k.gen
Census_data_10000_k.gen_01
Census_data_10000_k.gen_02
```

Comment: i have added the output  please check in above question.I have tried your way but the output is not according to requirement

Comment: @henrycharles - The answer is updated according to your updated question

Answer (score 0):

While your code is quite ugly it should work.

The only problem I can see would be a suboptimal block management. Also you are missing a trim() to cut lines consisting of only whitespaces. Try this instead:

```
    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        currentLine = currentLine.replace(delete,"").trim();
        if (!currentLine.isEmpty()) {
            writer.println(currentLine);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: i have added the output  please check in above question.I have tried your way but the output is not according to requirement